# Sum of inverse of a multiplicative function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-functions, multiplicative-function, mobius-inversion

I stumbled upon the following problem, while trying to come up with a recreational math question.

Let $n$ be a positive integer with factorization $n=2^a\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{e_i}$

Define the arithmetic function $$f(n)=2^{\left\lfloor \frac{a}{2} \right\rfloor}\prod_{i=1}^{k}p_i^{\left\lfloor\frac{e_i+1}{2}\right\rfloor}$$
For example, $n=120=2^3\cdot 3\cdot 5$, so $f(120)=2^1\cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^1=30$.

I need to evaluate the sum $$S(N)=\sum_{n=1}^{N}\left\lfloor\frac{N}{f(n)}\right\rfloor$$
When $N$ becomes large ($>10^8$ say), factorizing each number is out of question. I wonder if there is some möbius inversion kind of trick to get the sum for very large $N$, say $10^{14}$.

Comment: Do you really mean $N/f(n)$, or should it be $n/f(n)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, I meant $N / f(n)$. As $f(n) | n$, that one is relatively simpler. We can use general summation method for multiplicative function. For my problem, lots of $N / f(n)$ have same value. If we can somehow count them efficiently, it might be tractable.

Comment: For large $n, f(n) \approx \sqrt n$. So for large $N$, we can estimate $S(N) \approx 2N\sqrt N \approx 2Nf(N)$.